# Why am I getting only 100Mbps out of my 500Mbps subscription?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, connection

Recently I upgraded to a 500Mbps from 100Mbps. Running a speed test shows same results as before, not even overcoming 100Mbps. Why is it?

My cable setup is like this: `<ISP> - <MODEM> - <ROUTER> - <PC>`

Tried changing some settings in the router but still getting same results.If I go and check my speed in "Network and Sharing Center" still shows 100Mbps, exactly as much as it was before. Checked my cables and each has 8 pins. My router model is an [Archer C50 AC1200 Dual Band](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/cat-9_Archer-C50.html#specifications) router.

Comment: Most likely the machine or the router is only compatiable for 100mbit Ethernet. Check the spec on your devices.

Comment: We would need to know what network card your computer has, what kind of router you have, and what other devices on your network might be affecting things (and their type). It is likely, as @StevenDavison said, that something in there is limited to 100Mbps ethernet.

Comment: My router supports connections up to 1Gbps. I don't have an external internet card, it's integrated in my motherboard. In conclusion I'm paying more for nothing..

Comment: What does your router support?

Comment: @JHenny So what is the make/model of your motherboard?

Comment: Gigabyte G31M-ES2L

Comment: Your router probably supports only 100MBit/s. (Since your mobo seems to be equipped with Gigabit Ethernet). (The mobo is gigabit enabled)

Comment: My router model is Archer C50 AC1200 Dual Band. I have no idea why it doesn't work. Please help me fix this issue because I'm paying a lot of extra money

Comment: As said already, the router only supports Fast Ethernet on the wired connections (100 Mb). Your options are to 1. Replace the router with one that has Gigabit switch ports or 2. Use the wireless 802.11ac connection with an appropriate 802.11ac client adapter, because it will support higher speeds than the 100Mb ethernet. Those are the only 2 possible solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to replace your router with one that is Gigabit Ethernet capable.

Your [Archer C50 AC1200 router spec page](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/cat-9_Archer-C50.html#specifications) does not list it as having Gigabit, you only have 100Mbps ports:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The fact that you only have a 100Mbps WAN port means that it it the limiting factor to your internet speed.  If you had a 1Gbps WAN port and 100Mbps LAN ports then at least you might be able to get an aggregate boost to speed (multiple 100Mbps devices/Wifi at the same time), but as it is your router is limiting your internet at its WAN port.

You *might* have better speed **between** Wifi devices though:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: @JHenny You'll want to verify (by looking at the documentation) that your modem is also capable of the increased speed, and has the connections you want to support it.

Comment: Same is happening to me. How can it be that WiFi is theoretically faster on those routers? (Even if we know that wireles speed is never real).