# Why is my AC router maxing out at 100 Mbps wireless with 500 Mbps connection

Tags: wireless-router

I'm in the process of switching over from a cable connection to fibre.
Both are 500 Mbps download. From the cable router I'm getting ~250Mbps wireless to my laptop, so I know it's not a laptop issue.
From my fibre router it's maxing out at 100Mpbs.

Router: D-Link DIR-810L
I know it's not a Gigabit router, so it'll max out at 100Mbps with a direct connection, but wirelessly I should be expecting AC speeds similar to my cable router.
I've verified wall speed to be 500Mbps.

Similar question, but I need to go further, to: 
[Why am I getting only 100Mbps out of my 500Mbps subscription?](https://superuser.com/questions/1207542/why-am-i-getting-only-100mbps-out-of-my-500mbps-subscription)

Comment: If it's not a 1Gbps router, why do you expect the input (WAN port) to be capable of such high speeds?

Comment: 1Gbps would only refer to the ethernet connection, not the wireless. 
DIR-810L specs have AC wireless "Speeds up to 433Mbps (5Ghz)". Not expecting that, but something closer to AC speeds like with the cable router.

Comment: And how is the router connected to your ISP if not via Ethernet?

Comment: I assumed WAN would be able to support the advertised wireless speeds, even if the LAN couldn't. They definitely don't make it obvious that it doesn't. I'm getting a new router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

433Mbps speeds between wireless devices does not mean 433Mbps speeds to the internet.

> You may set the port speed of the Internet port to 10Mbps, 100Mbps, or
>   Auto 10/100Mbps (recommended).
>   [Page 86 in the Manual.](ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DIR-810L/REVB/DIR-810L_REVB_MANUAL_2.00_EN_US.PDF)

Your Dlink only has 10/100Mbps ports. The maximum speed to the internet will be less than 100Mbps.

[Begin Rant]It’s rather a shame Dlink would cheap out to this degree and then seemingly mislead their customers in such a manner.  You should take it back, or throw it in the trash and consider purchasing from a different company.[End Rant]

Comment: Agreed on the misleading advertising. I also assumed that the LAN would be 10/100, but the WAN would be able to provide the wireless speeds (for internet, not device-device).
Fortunately I bought used, so will just pass it on and upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Your router supports up to 100mbit in. This is the hardcap on data transmission speed from the Internet. I would highly recommend upgrading to a better router (perhaps from ASUS or Linksys), like one that has external antennae. This will help ensure you can get as close as possible to maxing out the wireless transmission speed and take advantage of your 500mbit connection as much as possible.